# Setting jqxGrid pagesize automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jqWidgets and I have a Grid but I want to set the "pagesize" dynamically depending on how many rows can fit on the page. - There is no 'auto' option.

So basically, I was thinking of getting the Height of the Grid and doing some calculation and then setting the pagesize, so if the row height was 20px for example, something like this:

```
var height =  $("#jqxgrid").height();
page = height*100/20;
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({pagesize : page});
```

Basically something like that but the calculation doesn't work properly as I am no good at maths! lol. Any idea's? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I have sorted it... this seems to work as an example:

```
var page =  $("#jqxgrid").height()-128;
pages = page/26;
valuetest = Math.round(pages);
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({pagesize : valuetest})
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is "auto" option. The option would be to set the Grid's "autoheight" setting to true so the Grid's height would depend only on the number of displayed rows.